# How create Custom Layout and Plugins for SwaggerUI externally in Angular 9

Tags: angular, swagger-ui

I'm working on Customizing the Swagger endpoints from outside Angular UI project. I'm using SwaggerUIBundle for this.

I'm exploring much on internet but not getting exactly how to create our own custom layouts and Plugins. 
Got very less helpful documentation on swagger official site and it is not helping me to create these things in my angular project.

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
presets: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
  SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
],
Plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,
]
layout: "StandaloneLayout"
```

})

Could you guys please help me out here with some examples on how create my own custom components, layout and plugins in my angular 9 code.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for similar code.

Answer (score 0):

In your swagger plugin component (or alternately by using window.swagger = swaggerUIBundle) you should make reference to swagger json (ie where `system` is referring to your swaggerUIBundle variable):

```
let mySwaggerJson = system.getSystem().spec().toJSON()
```

This gives us the clue that in that document is a loading status. This also won't give you what you want unless you call it after your document is loaded yet.

So what we can do is wait for the desired status on our swagger json (ie the status of it having loaded):

```
waitUntil = (condition: any, checkInterval = 100) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!condition()) {
          return;
        }
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve(null);
      }, checkInterval);
    });
  };

await waitUntil(() => system.specSelectors.loadingStatus() === 'success');

//This outputs the swagger as you would expect.
console.log(system.getSystem().spec().toJSON());
```

I had tried to intercept request and response which are do-able via swagger plugins but they didn't give me what I wanted. This did.